# Selenium python AutoLogin chrome at https://web.hi.com/#/

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

I tried to Autologin at https://web.hi.com/#/ over python with selenium.
I investigate the window for the phone number input and just found one ID = setValue.
When i try to interact with the ID im able to click at this window over selenium but
im not able to send keys :(. Maybe you can give me a short advice what I should search for :S sry for my bad English.
I got this error message

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/petergabriel/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.get("https://web.hi.com/#/")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("setValue")

search.send_keys("123456789")

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9i4t.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get("https://web.hi.com/#/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.uni-input-input"))).send_keys("123456789")
```

To send input to that element induce wait and then send keys. You have to target the input tag.

```
<input maxlength="20" step="0.000000000000000001" enterkeyhint="done" pattern="[0-9]*" autocomplete="off" type="number" class="uni-input-input">
```

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs

[image]

Comment: You are a genius thanks a lot god bless you

Comment: Accept the answer.